# Shifting/rescaling/standardizing coordinate system in spatial lines data frame using R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a `spatial lines data frame` object `extent: 143516.4, 213981, 3353367, 3399153  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

I want to standardize `x` and `y` coordinates and create the same spatial lines data frame object with a new `extent`.  I would say I want to rescale but rescale packages only use one argument I need `mean(xcoord)`, `mean(ycoord)` and move with `sd(xcoord)` and `sd(ycoord)`

Comment: You make no mention of using ArcMap so I've removed the tag for that so that your question can become focused on R.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: By "standardize" do you mean you want to transform the lines so that the vertex points over the data frame have (x,y) coordinates such that mean(x)=mean(y)=0, and sd(x)=sd(y)=1?